# How to open "PPT file with new" option in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have below code to open the ppt file, but I need to open that file with new option (Refer image). So that existing file will not be disturbed unknowingly. Any help please.

```
Sub openfile()
Dim objPP As Object
Dim objPPFile As Object
Set objPP = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
objPP.Visible = True
Set objPPFile = objPP.Presentations.Open("E:\Test\Tempplate.pptx")
End Sub
```

Comment: Can we see the image please!

Comment: Can you tag this as [powerpoint] as well.

Comment: **that existing file will not be disturbed unknowingly...** open it as readonly? `objPP.Presentations.Open FileName:="E:\Test\Tempplate.pptx", ReadOnly:=-1` You can read more about it in [Presentations.Open method (PowerPoint)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.presentations.open)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub openfile()
Dim objPP As Object
Dim objPPFile As Object
Set objPP = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
objPP.Visible = True
ts = Format(Now(), "MMDDYYYY_HHMM")
fn = "E:\Test\New_" & Trim(ts) & ".pptx"
FileCopy "E:\Test\Tempplate.pptx", fn
Set objPPFile = objPP.Presentations.Open(fn)
End Sub
```

Comment: May you could try this if this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot for instant help, it worked perfectly.